# iPhone In App Purchase prompting login on addTransactionObserver on completely new device with new user

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am calling `addTransactionObserver:` in my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching method, and it immediately prompts the user to either log in to their iTunes account, or to input the password if they are already logged in. This happens to new users who have never installed the app before. If they input the password, nothing happens, and the app is fine, but they are then prompted for their password again when they want to buy something. Regardless, the app shouldn't be asking a user to log in to their iTunes account when all it has done is launch.

I know that there are issues that can arise from not calling `finishTransaction:` where the transaction can get stuck in a weird state and prompt the user to log in until it is finished. However, in my case, I have deleted ALL sandbox test users, created a brand new one, installed the app fresh, and it still immediately prompts me to log in, or input my password if I already have logged in. I have factory reset the device, and it still behaves this way.

I think it may be some old unfinished transactions that were associated with other test user accounts, but since they are deleted, I have no way of checking. Is there something else I can do to stop the login prompt from showing?

Comment: I have a somewhat related issue: When my app calls addTransactionObserver and still has an unfinished transaction in the queue, it sometimes pops up the login dialog. You wrote that "there are issues that can arise ... [when an unfinished] transaction [gets] stuck in a weird state". I think this is what I'm seeing. Could you share a link about these weird states that you mentioned? Do you know if there is a way to prevent this? Thank you! (+1 x 2)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, the reason was that I was creating a `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` as well and sending that request at app launch.

To summarize for anyone else having a similar problem, the steps to resolve the Alert popping up are:

Ensure that you don't have any unfinished transactions in the queue. If you call `addTransactionObserver:` and there are unfinished transactions, it will call `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` and you can then call `finishTransaction:` on them.

Delete the sandbox test users in iTunes connect that aren't being used. If you've logged in to one of those accounts on a device, it can ask you to log in to that account for some reason.

Make sure you are ONLY calling `addTransactionObserver:` on app initialization. An `SKRequest` will ask the user to log in.

Comment: Nah, sorry I've tried absolutely everything and there's something else making it ask to login. ALL I'm doing is calling addTransactionObserver. That's it. Period. I've set breakpoints on every single spot where In-App purchase logic is found. I've deleted all internal testing and sandbox testing accounts from iTunes connect and logged out of everything from the device. When I call "addTransactionObserver" it STILL asks the user to login....every.....single....time.  It's preventing me from submitting my app. Any ideas?